# How to get the grouped product price with a quantity of added products

Tags: magento2, price, grouped-products

I'm using this code to get grouped product price in this file "`Magento_GroupedProduct\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml`":

```
<?php
$products = $block->getSaleableItem()
    ->getTypeInstance()
    ->getAssociatedProducts($block->getSaleableItem());

$priceForAll = 0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $priceForAll += $product
        ->getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE);
}
?>
<div class="price-box" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <?php if ($priceForAll && \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_VIEW != $block->getZone()): ?>
    <span class="price">$<?php echo number_format($priceForAll,2,'.',',')?></span>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

But this sums up the total cost of all added goods without counting the quantity. I have no problem on the product page because I'm using JS to count price dynamically

[image]

But I have an incorrect price on the category page

[image]

How can I check the quantity of all added products and show the correct price?

Thanks!